# Drop rows of pandas dataframe that don't have finite values in certain variable(s)

Tags: pandas, notnull

I cannot see what the built-in function is for the following simple but seemingly common/useful task: Drop rows which have no value for any of my key columns.

```
def keepIfPopulated(adf,interestingVars):
        good=0
        for vv in interestingVars:
            good+=adf[vv].notnull()
        return(adf[good>0])
```

If there was just one column of interest, I could choose to keep it, but most pandas functions take one or more labels as arguments, so this question is about how to check on one *or more* columns at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
adf = adf.dropna(subset=interestingVars, how='all')
```