# Find row index of pandas dataframe that don't have finite values

Tags: python, pandas, notnull

I have a large dataframe that I want to split when all columns are nan or don't have a finite value. I am looking for something similar to the post [Drop rows of pandas dataframe that don't have finite values in certain variable(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15626215/drop-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-that-dont-have-finite-values-in-certain-variable) but rather than dropping I'd like to split on those rows.

I am currently on pandas 0.16.0

Comment: does `df[df.apply(lambda x: x.isnull().all(), axis=1)]` work?

Comment: Also doesn't `df.dropna(how='all')` return you this?

Comment: @EdChum absolutely perfect. Thank you. the dropna returns the dataframe without the nans, not the rows with the nans.

Comment: Which worked, the first suggestion?, it will be slow for a large df, not sure if it's quicker to do `df.loc[df.index.difference(df.dropna(how='all').index)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be quicker to filter the non-`NaN` rows from your df by calling `index.difference` on the index labels returned from `dropna`:

```
In [69]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,np.NaN, 0], 'b':[np.NaN, np.NaN, 1]})
df = pd.concat([df]*10000, ignore_index=True)   

%timeit df[df.apply(lambda x: x.isnull().all(), axis=1)]
%timeit df.loc[df.index.difference(df.dropna(how='all').index)]

1 loops, best of 3: 2.82 s per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 8.95 ms per loop
```

You can see that for a 30k row df, the latter method is much faster

Answer (score 1):

As @EdChum has pointed out

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x.isnull().all(), axis=1)]
```

does the trick.